# MVC 6 code first object ignores foreign key restriction when inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a Web API project using MVC 6 and the tutorial found on [this page](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html).

I created a User class in the Models folder and a Level class. The relation between them is that a User has a Level, so the Level is associated with many Users (1 to many, I guess). Here's what each class has:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string username { get; set; }

    //More attributes

    [Required]
    public int levelNumber { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("levelNumber")]
    public virtual Level level { get; set; }
}

public class Level
{
    [Key]
    public int levelNumber { get; set; }

    //More attributes

    public virtual ICollection<User> users { get; set; }
}
```

Ok so after I create the Repositories and Controllers for each class, I use Fiddler to POST some requests and feed the database. I create a level with id 1 with this JSON: `{"levelNumber":"1", "name":"First Level", "icon":"myicon", "min_score":"0"}`. It's created with no problems.

Then I want to create a new User and it should reference the Level class with id 1, but apparently it's ignoring it. Also, if I create a new user using a non-existing levelNumber, it should not create the user because the foreign key does not exist, but it creates the user anyway. I use this JSON to create the user referencing level 1:
`{"username":"myuser", "fbID":"x", "firstname":"Name", "lastname":"Lastname", "gender":"male", "location":"GT", "levelNumber":"1"}`. Then I create a new user referencing to level 2 (which does not exist): `{"username":"myuser2", "fbID":"x", "firstname":"Name", "lastname":"Lastname", "gender":"male", "location":"GT", "levelNumber":"2"}`. This is what I get when I do a GET request for the levels and the users:

Levels:
[image]

Users:
[image]

What is wrong with my models or my logic? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you checked the database? foreign key reference exists on the column in the user table? Are you sure you are not catching and swallowing exceptions?

Comment: How can I check the database? Whenever I run my project on localhost all the previous data is erased. Also when I publish to Azure, all previous data is erased.

Comment: When you create the user with the non-existent level 2 does it create a new level object with a key of 2 as well?

Comment: You can run once, then go to database and check, data is not necessary to check schema properties though.

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: Hey @Mathew, I created a new question regarding exploring the localdb database, I would thank you if you could help me there! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229687/find-database-of-web-api-project-on-visual-studio-2015-localdb

Answer (score 1):

You should include level while selecting User.

```
  Context.Users.Include(x=>x.Level)
```

Comment: Where should I use this? I don't understand where to put it.

Comment: How you select user ?

Comment: I use a ConcurrentDictionary and just return all data using return _users.Values;

Answer (score 0):

Put [ForeignKey("Level")]  data annotation on top of User.levelNumber property  and remove it from  public virtual Level level { get; set; }

It should be:

```
[Required]
[ForeignKey("Level")]
public int levelNumber { get; set; }

public virtual Level level { get; set; }
```