# Find database of Web API project on Visual Studio 2015 LocalDB

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, localdb

I'm developing a Code First Web API using ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6. I can test my models and controllers locally and in Azure using a publish profile, but I want to see if the database is applying some constraints. I read that I can see the database's Tables and Columns using the SQL Server Object Explorer.

When I go to View > SQL Server Object Explorer I can see the following:

(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB
(localdb)\ProjectsV12
(localdb)\v11.0

I know that v11.0 was used on VS 2012 and it was changed to MSSQLLocalDB on VS 2015 (I don't know what ProjectsV12 is doing there). So I open (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB > Databases and I only see a System Databases subfolder, I can't find my project's database. Am I looking on the right place? Am I missing a step? Thanks for your help.

Here's a pic of what I see.

[image]

Comment: Try to search in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances`. You should find here `MSSQLLocalDB` and `ProjectsV12` folders with the data.

Comment: You can add a new connection from that top toolbar. Click on `add sql server` button, the one with a green plus on your screenshot. Why can't you just check out the icons and toolbar buttons before asking every basic question?